# Set default unit for information rate and others

Tags: units

I am using mathematica to convert units to canonical form, like I have `0.2 KBYTE/s` and I want to get `200`. So I want to see all 'information' units as `Bytes`, but default interpretation is `Bits`. Is it somehow possible to set? I will want "bits" for "information rate" and "bytes" for "information amount"-  which is how people are used to measure these.

Here is what I have:

```
x=UnitConvert[Quantity[0.2,"KBYTE/s"]];x/Quantity[1,QuantityUnit[x]]
1600
```

which is the answer in `bits` but I want it to be in `bytes`

Comment: `UnitConvert[Quantity[0.2, "kB/s"], "B/s"]`?

Comment: I do not know the unit in advance, it can be bits/s or just megabytes or even kilograms. So I can not use what you suggested, I need a way to set default sub-unit set (I know how to set to metric units but I need to set non-defined defaults also, like bytes over bits I mentioned, which are not standardized in SI)